# Irreducible polynomial of degree two over a finite field with one alternating coefficient

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p(x) = x^2 -ax + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_q[x] $ where $q > 3$ is a prime. For what values of $a \in \mathbb{Z}_q $ is $p(x) $ irreducible, *i.e.* has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_q $?

For instance, consider $ \mathbb{F}_4 = \{ 0,1, \alpha, \alpha + 1 \}$. The polynomials $p(x) = x^2 - \alpha x + 1 $ and $q(x) = x^2 - ( \alpha + 1 )x +1 $ are irreducible, but not when $a = 0$ or $a = 1$.

But if $\mathbb{F}_q = \mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4 \}$ then $p(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible, *i.e* when $a = 1$.

I do not necessarily need to limit the field to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, it can be $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, but it is perhaps easier to begin in that end. I was wondering if there is any results involving this and what the intuition is behind it?

Best regards

Comment: What's wrong with just using the standard quadratic formula?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It seems like for odd $q$ we have $\frac{q-1}{2}$ irreducible polynomials of the form $x^2 + ax + 1$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3778944/723277). How does one come to the conclusion for $x^2 - ax + 1$?

Comment: I think we can rewrite $a'=-a$, so it doesn't matter. So the reference still is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778917/counting-irreducible-polynomials-of-the-form-x2-ax-1-over-a-finite-field?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I don't quite understand the argument about $ \mathbb{F}_{q^2} \setminus \mathbb{F}_{q}$, care to explain that one? :)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. Thanks for the reference!